# Why doesn't this CSS code work as expected?

Tags: html, css

Can someone kindly tell me why the following CSS code I have doesn't work? I am completely drawing a blank on the why, this is not my first rodeo.

I have added the following code to **END** of the CSS file to ensure that nothing else will override it:

```
address,
span,
.gStyle {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:small;
    text-transform:capitalize;
}

.gStyle .ngs address {
    color: red;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.gStyle .sgs span {
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

and I have called the classes in the code as follows:

```
<address class="ngs">lorem ipsum</address>
<span class="sgs">lorem ipsum</span>
```

but what I expected to happen which is the content in the,

- `address` would come back as BOLD+CAPITALIZED+RED+10PX and the content in,
- `span` would come back as BOLD+CAPITALIZED+BLACK+12PX while any calls directly to,
- `gStyle` would return BOLD+SMALL+CAPITALIZED.

This is not happening, so what am I doing wrong? I have been coding too long to not see what's wrong but I also a big enough man to say, hey you must be missing something, so ask.

### EDIT - CLARIFICATION

Actually what I need is that when I apply `CLASS="ngs"` to any element for that matter but at the very least to `ADDRESS` it will apply both the styles that are in `gStyle` which is the base style but also apply the `ngs` additional style. I tried using the `CLASS="gStyle ngs"` but that didn't work either. Same logic applies to the `sgs` so can you tell me what I am doing wrong with that in mind? I am sorry it wasn't more clear, I thought the bullet point expected results would be sufficient along with the HTML snippet.

Answer (score 3):

`.gStyle .ngs address` selects an `address` element within a `.ngs` element within a `.gStyle` element.

It looks like you want an `address` element that *is* a `.ngs` element within a `.gStyle` element, which would make your code:

```
.gStyle address.ngs
```

same goes for the span:

```
.gStyle span.sgs
```

Comment: I added some information that might clarify what I need, I am not looking for an element to inherit form within, but rather inherit a base style in addition another on a any element that has that class name given to it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems.

```
.gStyle .ngs address {
    color: red;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

This code block will target all the `address` tags within an element with `.ngs` class which is within an element with `.gStyle` Class. Same goes for your span. A space between class names suggests a parent child relation between two classes.

To target your current HTML markup it should be:

```
.gStyle address.ngs {
    color: red;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

This is assuming your `<address>` is within an element with `.gStyle` class.
Same goes for span.